# How to copy SVN repository to another repository in Eclipse using subclipse

Tags: svn, subclipse

We are using SVN Repository in our Project. We need to create a copy of 
repository in different repository. I want to do using Subclipse in Eclipse. But I do not find any way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot copy a repository via a SVN client.  Copying a repository would entail copying the filesystem contents on the server or doing a dump/load on the server.